# Prove that a number raised to a prime is equal to itself and a multiple of the prime?

Tags: induction

How do I prove using induction that any number a that is greater than or equal to 1, raised to a power k(which is prime) will be equal to a + kq, where q is some integer?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: This is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the group theory proof:  $\mathbb (Z/kZ)^*$ is a group,  with order $k-1$.  By Lagrange's theorem,  the order of every element divides the order of the group.   Therefore $a^{k-1}\cong1\pmod k$.  Now multiply through by $a$.

But, to do it by induction, use the "freshman's dream ", which is true in characteristic k:  $(x+y)^k=x^k+y^k$.

With that, the inductive step is easy:   assume $a^k=a$.  Then $(a+1)^k=a^k+1^k=a+1$.